# Excel2013 can't write in the status bar?

Tags: vba, excel, statusbar, excel-2013

i want to write in the statusbar of Excel 2013, at the opening of the document Excel so i have puted the following code in thisWorkbook:

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents app As Excel.Application 

Private Sub app_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook) 
   app.DisplayStatusBar = True 
   If UCase$(Wb.Path) = "C:\GED\TEMP" Then 
      app.StatusBar = "ok" 
   Else 
      app.StatusBar = "ko" 
  EndIF 
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
 Set app = Application
End Sub
```

but i have always error in the method statusbar of _Application. it takes always false i dont know why please any idea or help.

Comment: Put a `msgbox Wb.Path` before the line `If UCase...` What do you see?

Comment: KekuSemau when i download the EXCEL FILE from the internet, msgbox Wb.Path is empty, so ?????please help

Comment: Basicly, the code seems to work right (I don't have 2013 here though), not much more I can say at the momemt.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim wbPath,capPath

Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
wbPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path            'ThisWorkbook.Path
capPath = "C:\GED\TEMP"

   If UCase$(wbPath) = capPath Then
   Application.StatusBar = "Ok."
   Else
   Application.StatusBar = "ko."
   End If

End If
```

Comment: Hi ZAT, the problem is that i need Application-level events to trap the opening of any workbook.because when i use Private Sub Workbook_Open() , i can't find the path and vba dont know the active workbook

Comment: not getting your point. You want to sense opening of any workbooks and you put your code under thisworkbook of a workbook. right?

Comment: i want to create a vba macro for excel 2013. this vba macro must be available for all excel files, i make a search in the internet and i found that i must put the code in Excel add-in, so i try to make a code for event opening of excel; when i use workbook_Open without event the problem is that when i open excel file, vba dont know the active workbook because it opens the add-in file  first then my current file,so i  need Application-level events.

Comment: try using `Activeworkbook.Path` in above posted code in place of `ThisWorkbook.Path`

Comment: i tried it ZAT but i have this error :Run-time error '91 ': Object variable or With block variable not set. the same error activeworkbook or Thisworkbook, so i used Application-level events,

Comment: Sorry Zat when i used ThisWorkbook.Path , it returns the path of file in the addin which is C:\....\Microsoft\AddIn, not the path that i want

Comment: remove the $ after ucase

Comment: and rename the sub to app_Workbook_Open     ,     mind both "_" !!

Answer (score 0):

rename the sub to app_Workbook_Open , mind both "_" !!

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents app As Excel.Application 

Private Sub app_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook) 
with app
    .DisplayStatusBar = True 
    If UCase(Wb.Path) = "C:\GED\TEMP" Then 
        .StatusBar = "ok" 
    Else 
       .StatusBar = "ko" 
    EndIF 
end with
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Set app = Application
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not put the macro in the personal workbook?